Elliptic curve point "division" by an integer
I am trying to understand whether given a point $Q$ that lies on an elliptic curve $C$ there exists a point $P$ on $C$ such that $n P = Q$ for a given $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In particular I would like to know whether such a $P$ exists if $n=3$.
If such points do exists, is there an easy way to prove it?

This is not true in general. For example, let $C$ be any elliptic curve over a number field of rank $r>0$, then the group of rational points is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^r\times T$, where $T$ is some finite group. Take $x=(1,0,\ldots,0)$ inside this group. Since $1/3 \notin \Bbb Z$, there is no element in this group that, when multiplied by $3$ gives $x$.
It's however true if the base field is algebraically closed and not of characteristic $3$ (or in general the characteristic doesn't divide $n$).

Thanks! I'm interested in the case of the field being $\mathbb{C}$. Would you by any chance know where I could find the proof in the case of alebraically closed fields?

See here. Though over $\Bbb C$ you could argue that any elliptic curve is just a torus, so you just need to prove this property for the concrete group $(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z)^2$, where it is easy
